# Google Chrome Dev tools can not show body content in Elements Tag

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Anybody have the situation like this:
Under Chrome Dev tools's Elements tag, body tag's content can not show.

[image]

The only method is close the dev tool and reopen.

Comment: Looks like https://crbug.com/829884. If you encounter this frequently you can switch to Chrome Canary.

Comment: hi, wOxxOm, i can't open the link.My Chrome Version is :Version 66.0.3359.117 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: It's a known bug in 66.

Comment: Just to add to this, you can refresh just the dev tools using "alt+r". This will fix the issue without needing to refresh the page.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It's a Chrome bug, it still happens in Canary, [crbug.com/829884](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=829884).

Refresh Devtools with <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> to fix if it happens.

Edit: update - bug fixed

Answer (score 2):

Bug disappeared after I forced Chrome to look for new updates and let it update to the latest version.

My version is now

> Version 67.0.3396.62 (Official Build) (64-Bit)

Comment: yes, it seems chrome fixed the bug and released.
in crbug.com/829884, they turn the issue status to fixed.