# Element does not expand in the Chrome Dev Tools when I command it to expand. Why?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

Sometimes when I command the `body` tag on a page I am inspecting to expand (by clicking with the mouse or using the arrow keys) it does not expand. As you can see in the screen capture the arrow next to the `body` tag is pointing downwards but no content is showing. I know that there is content in the `body` tag. The `head` tag expands just fine.

When this happens problem occurs I have found that a workaround is to open the url in a new tab. When I do that, I can again expand the body tag and enjoy the full power of the Chrome Dev Tools.

This happens very often. During the last week I have found myself having to reopen the page I am inspecting several 10s of times a day.

[image]

Comment: Do you have any add ons on your dev tools? I have recently been experiencing a similar issue, and think it may be because of the React Dev tools plugin.

Comment: That is probably it. I do have the React Dev tools plugin. I worked around the problem by running Chrome Canary Version 69.0.3448.0 (Official Build) canary (64-bit). I have not experienced the problem on this version of Chrome.

Comment: Ah, sorry - I lost this post, but actually found another stack overflow question about this, and upgrading Chrome to the latest stable version (67) it resolved the issue, and it was not related to the React Dev tools plugin at all - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50033710/google-chrome-dev-tools-can-not-show-body-content-in-elements-tag